# Can't restrict method by Lower-bound rule

Tags: scala, generics, lower-bound

I've started to read about scala generics.  Who can explain me why whit code work?

```
sealed abstract class Animal

class Cat extends Animal
class Dog extends Animal

class Box[A >: Animal] {
  def set(a: A): A = ???
}

val catBox: Box[Animal] = new Box[Animal]
val dog = new Dog
catBox.set(dog)
```

Comment: It works fine actually (save for `???`, that has nothing to do with generics ... or anything really). For the future, when asking a question, try explaining a specific problem you are looking for help with, just "does not work" is way too broad. Do not expect people to guess, what you mean by that.

Comment: Oh yes, it is my fault. The problem is why I can call method set(dog) if I restrict type A by lower bound - Animal. Because Dog is subtype of Animal, not a supertype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing here, that what you mean by "does not work" is that you did not expect to be able to `set` a `Dog` into your `catBox`, because `Dog` is not a superclass of `Animal`.

This is expected though. Your definition of `Box[Animal].set` becomes 
`def set(a: Animal): Animal`. Now, a `Dog` *is* an `Animal`, so, it satisfies the definition.

I don't quite understand what your intent is here. The type bound on `Box` restricts what kinds of boxes you can create:

```
 new Box[Animal] // compiles
 new Box[Dog]    // does not compile - Dog is not a superclass of Animal
 new Box[Any]    // compiles - Any is a superclass of everything
```

but why would you want to restrict it like this doesn't make very much sense.
Perhaps, you wanted the upper bound instead:

```
 class AnimalBox[A <: Animal]
 val animalBox = new AnimalBox[Animal] // compiles
 val dogBox = new AnimalBox[Dog] // compiles: Dog is a subclass of Animal
 val catBox = new AnimalBox[Cat] // compiles: Cat is a subclass of Animal
 val badBox = new AnimalBox[Any] // does not compile: Any is not a subclass

 animalBox.set(new Dog) // compiles: Dog is an Animal
 animalBox.set(new Cat) // compiles: Cat is an Animal
 animalBox.set(new Pear) // does not compile: Pear is not an Animal

 dogBox.set(new Dog) // compiles
 dogBox.set(new Cat) // does not compile: cat is not a dog
```

Answer (score 0):

Operator `???` is equivalent to `throw new NotImplementedError`.

So, when you call `catBox.set(dog)`, you are throwing an exception.